# Changing image source of an imageview in a different layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, nullpointerexception

I can't find a solution to this anywhere, I'm still quite new to programming so it might be a simple question.

In my `MainActivity` I take the position of a `ViewPager`. According to this position I want to change the source of an `ImageView` which is placed in a layout that will inflate in a service. But with my code I keep getting a `NullPointerException`.
Do I need to declare the `ImageView` differently because it's in a different layout than the currently showed one?

```
 public void OnClick(View view) {


    pagenumber = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.filterview);

    switch (pagenumber){
        case 0: imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.goghfilter);
            break;
        case 1: imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.background3);
            break;
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well remember that the class inflated with the layout will only find views in that layout, try to findById a view not in that layout will cause errors.
To resolve this, define a custom layout inflater, inflate the layout with the image , then used that view inflated and perform a findById on it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,

I tried the following:
`LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.overlay, null);
        imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.filterview);`
Which got rid of the error, but it didnt seem to change the source of the imageview. Is this what you meant?

Comment: yea, tell me how to confirm this change of source, visually? how is the that particular image related to the activity and binding layout.

Comment: Visually yes, If it works a different image than the default source should show up on top of everything else when I select a different option. I tested if the select number was changing and that's working fine. So the problem is in changing the source. The image is not related to the activity at all, it's an imageview in a layout that shows up when a service is started.

Comment: That's ok. I found a way around, thanks for the replies.

Comment: which is? i am curious

Comment: I passed the number of the selected item from the activity to the service and changed the image source there with your method.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```html
ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout,null).findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
```